# Sending a form to an email address and also being able to save/load it from a cookie

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms, cookies

I am creating a form which saves to a cookie and also posts results to an email address.

The problem is, when they are both used together they do not work. I can either have the form sent to an email address OR have the form saved/loaded from a cookie. I need both.

Two questions:

1. http://www.irt.org/articles/js025/ < That is what I'm currently using, if you check the comments everyone is having the same problem and the programmer has not responded to the problems. Any ideas on how to use THIS code while sending a form to an email address using PHP (form written in html like this code)?
2. Are there any good alternatives to allow my form to send to an email address while also being able to save/load it to and from a cookie?

Regards.

Comment: You need a server side technology to send email, and if you're going to involve one anyway then there is no reason not to use it to set the cookies too. Forget about JavaScript and focus on normal form submissions that you process with PHP (since that is the common server side technology you've tagged the question with).

Comment: I see, what @Aerik says also backs this up. I understand why it doesn't work now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that it doesn't save to the cookie until *after* it reloads the page using the default action and method (GET) which results in a querystring.  The script loads the values in this line

```
var searchString = replace(self.location.search.substring(1),"+"," ");
```

and then sets the cookie right after that

```
if (searchString.length > 0) Set_Cookie("userProfile",searchString,expires);
```

If you leave it the default action and method, then use PHP to grab the values from $_GET to put in your email, it will work.

EDIT, untested example code

```
<?php

$myemailAddr = "your email address";
$mailStr = "";
$subject = "New Signup";

foreach($_GET as $key=>$value){
  $mailStr .= $key.":".$value."\n";
}

mail($myemailAddr,$subject,$mailStr);

?>
//your form and javascript etc go here
```

Comment: I'm quite a PHP amateur, any chance you can point me in the right direction of how to do this?

Comment: You'd use the php mail function (see http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) and retrieve the form values from $_GET (see http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) - the $_GET values are the form element names, like $_GET['user'] and $_GET['age']